# How do I prevent SQL Server 2008 stored procedure from writing line breaks to a file?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

This is what we have so far, which works, but it writes out line breaks to the file. We would like to not send the CRLF character if at all possible.

```
set @dosvar = @JobNumber
set @doscmd2 = 'ECHO' + @dosvar +' >> \\test1\websites\testcontrol\js\misc1.js'

Exec master..xp_cmdshell @doscmd2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [this trick](http://www.devtrends.com/index.php/echo-without-carriage-return-or-line-feed-cr-lf/):

```
'echo/|set /p="' + @dosvar +'" >> \\test1\websites\testcontrol\js\misc1.js'
```

If you run this batch file:

```
@echo off
echo/|set /p="a"
echo/|set /p="b"
echo/|set /p="c"
```

It prints:

```
abc
```

So it seems to work.

Comment: Cheers, that helps a ton - I tried googling, but I just didn't know what to search!